# How to read a file continuously?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I want to read a file continuously , I mean if I found an end of file , I want to read it again from first. So I am reseting the stream but it is not working. Here is my code.

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Abc.txt"));
        while(true)
        {

            sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
            if(sCurrentLine!=null)
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            else
                br.reset();

        }
```

can anyone help me in this please.

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: @Harry I m not getting , any idea about `mark()` method bfore `reset()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to recreate the `BufferedReader` once `readLine()` returns `null`.

For example:

```java
String filename = "[filename]";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line != null)
        // Use line
    else {
        reader.close();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of always reading straight from the file without storing too much of it in memory at a time, which could be a concern if, as you've said, it contains five thousand lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Abc.txt"));
while(true) {
     sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
     if(sCurrentLine!=null) {
          System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
     } else {
          br.close();
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Abc.txt"));
     }
}
```

So it will restart with a fresh BufferedReader :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `br.mark(100);` after initialising `br`

```
Marks the present position in the stream. Subsequent calls to reset()
will attempt to reposition the stream to this point.
```

On parameter `readAheadLimit`:

> readAheadLimit Limit on the number of characters that may be read
>   while still preserving the mark. An attempt to reset the stream after
>   reading characters up to this limit or beyond may fail. A limit value
>   larger than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer to be
>   allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values
>   should be used with care.

The following code will continuously print the contents of the file `/home/user/temp/reader.test`

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/temp/reader.test"));
    String sCurrentLine;

    br.mark(100);
    while(true)
    {
        sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
        if(sCurrentLine!=null)
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        else
            br.reset();
    }
```

Comment: yes . . ,what is 100 here , I have 5000 of line in a file , if it reach end, again it has to read from first , but if I put 100 i m getting exception.

Comment: `readAheadLimit Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still preserving the mark.` So if you know the amount of characters in the file, set it accordingly, or set it to a number large enough to be safe. If this is not an option, re-opening the buffer would be the cleanest.